# How to use thumbnails in Laravel and store them on AWS S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, thumbnails, liipimaginebundle

I need to implement convenient way to create thumbnails into Laravel Framework. But I want to store everything on Amazon S3. I checked this package https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-image but it doesn't have possibility to store cache of thumbnails on s3. I checked http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/index.html but it works good with Symfony and I don't know if it will work easy with Laravel. Do you have any experience in solving such problems?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is to use [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/).

```
$image = Image::make($file)->resize($width, $height)->save();
```

and then you just do the standard `s3->put` and store the path into your database.

```
$s3->put($path, $image->__toString(), 'public');
$url = $this->s3->url($path);
```

I didn't thoroughly read through [this](http://www.phpgang.com/image-upload-and-resize-using-image-intervention-in-laravel_889.html) but it might give you some more insight on how to use Intervention.